# How to have a constant records from array in subreport?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

How to do in order to have a constant limit records for each value in subreport ?

Answer (score 0):

When you define the `datasource expresion`of your subreport you can apply the sublist function:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{list}.subList(0,100))
```

in your xml, you will have something like:

```
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="x" y="x" width="xx" height="xx" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="xx" uuid="xxx"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{list}.subList(0,100))]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression>xxxxx</subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

Comment: the link place inside subreport xml coding there?